# How to filter based on first occurrence in my table using SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server.

Here is my table:

```
RepID  ICD  Diagnosed  RandStat
-------------------------------
1001   A    1          11
1002   A    0          11
1003   A    0          11
1005   A    1          11

1003   A    1          22
1005   A    0          22
1008   A    1          22
1009   A    0          22

1001   A    0          33
1004   A    1          33
1005   A    0          33
1007   A    0          33

1003   A    0          44
1004   A    0          44
1005   A    1          44
1007   A    1          44


1001   B    0          11
1004   B    1          11
1006   B    1          11
1008   B    1          11

1004   B    0          22
1006   B    1          22
1008   B    0          22
1009   B    1          22

1001   B    0          33
1002   B    1          33
1003   B    1          33
1006   B    0          33

1003   B    1          44
1004   B    0          44
1005   B    0          44
1007   B    1          44
```

I want to filter out the repeated RepIDs for the same ICD based on the first RandStat (`ordered by RandStat`).

So if RepID appeared on RandStat 11, then it should be removed from RandStat 22 or above (all for the same ICD)

The final results should look like this:

```
RepID  ICD  Diagnosed  RandStat
-------------------------------
1001   A    1          11
1002   A    0          11
1003   A    0          11
1005   A    1          11

1008   A    1          22
1009   A    0          22

1004   A    1          33
1007   A    0          33

1001   B    0          11
1004   B    1          11
1006   B    1          11
1008   B    1          11

1009   B    1          22

1002   B    1          33
1003   B    1          33

1005   B    0          44
1007   B    1          44
```

I tried this query

```
SELECT A.*
FROM MyTable A 
INNER JOIN MyTable B ON A.RepID = B.RepID
                     AND A.ICD = B.ICD
                     AND A.RandStat < B.RandStat
```

but this took me nowhere....

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: SQL does not guarantee a sort order. You can't rely on the entry order being the order in which rows are retrieved. How are you defining the 'first RandStat' in this table?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular RandStat is coming from another system. It is used for a purpose, although field name is RandStat but it is not Random

Comment: You need a column(s) which provides the ordering you think is there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the  order based on RandStat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ICD, RepID ORDER BY RandStat) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT RepID, ICD, Diagnosed, RandStat
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ICD, RandStat, RepID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to solve your problem

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        B.*
FROM (
        SELECT 
                repID,
                ICD,
                MIN(Randstat) as RandStat
        FROM Table
        GROUP BY repid,icd
     ) AS A
INNER JOIN Table AS B
    ON A.repID = B.repID AND A.ICD = B.ICD AND A.RandStat = B.RandStat;
```

As for my system, this solution is about 2 times faster but has more logical reads...
You can check both and decide yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's asolution using `NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT RepID, ICD, Diagnosed, RandStat  
FROM MyTable A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM MyTable B
    WHERE A.RepID = B.RepID
        AND A.ICD = B.ICD
        AND A.RandStat > B.RandStat
    )
```

This uses extremely similar logic to your query, but instead of using it as a join condition it checks for any rows matching the conditions, and if any are found then that row is excluded.